# practical use of pointer to member nontype template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

What is the use case for pointer to member as a nontype template parameter?

for example:

```
class X {
public:
    int n;
};


template <typename T, T nontype_param>
class C
{
public:
    void doSomething()
    {
        //what goes here to access or use nontype_param?
    }
};

void test()
{
    C<int X::*, &X::n> c;
    c.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps for use with POD structures? Without some context it's really hard to say anything for certain.

Comment: something like `X x; x.*nontype_param = 42;` ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - just something I came across while reading about templates. Don't really have much more context than that, hence the question about the use case :)

Comment: @Jarod42 - thanks. That answers the second question.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes from Bjarne's book:

A type template parameter can be used as a type later in a template parameter list. For example:

```
template<typename T, T default_value>
class Vec {
 // ...
};

Vec<int,42> c1;
Vec<string,""> c2;
```

This becomes particularly useful when combined with a default template argument (§25.2.5); for
example:

```
template<typename T, T default_value = T{}>
class Vec {
    // ...
};

Vec<int,42> c1;
Vec<int> c11; // default_value is int{}, that is, 0

Vec<string,"for tytwo"> c2;
Vec<string> c22; // default_value is string{}; that is, ""
```